# Does an Euler-Maruyama scheme correspond to a unique Ito SDE?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

The Euler-Maruyama (EM) scheme looks at least superficially like the most natural discretization of an SDE, just like the Euler-method for ODEs.
However, it's strong order of converge is only 1/2. As I recall from (Milstein & Tretyakov, stochastic numerics for mathematical physics), this implies that during a single timestep h, also a deviation of order h occurs. The EM scheme is thus not 'tangential' to the exact solution.
Given this situation, is an EM actually unique to a certain SDE, or can different SDEs share the same EM scheme? This confuses me a bit.

As a more practical follow-up, consider a set of two coupled stochastic variables x(t), y(t) and compare the following situations

- y(0)=0, and after every timestep, $y(t+\Delta t)$ is projected back to 0.
- the equation for y(t) is replaced by y(t)=0 at all times

Would these correspond to the same process in the limit $\Delta t\rightarrow0$ as they share the same EM scheme?

Comment: How would you get the non-uniqueness? From the method equation you can read off the coefficients of the SDE. Or do you mean to reconstruct the SDE from (a represantative sample of) numerical trajectories?

Comment: @LutzLehmann that's exactly what confuses me. In that sense, I would also think that an SDE is equivalent with it's EM scheme. But still, it confuses me that, (given a fixed noise record) if you let the SDE evolve for an infinitesimal timestep along with its EM scheme, the deviation doesn't vanish asymptotically... thinking about a concrete example now. Maybe if you have two coupled variables, EM misses their Ito contribution at first order.

Comment: For the leading error term you get a global error contribution of $$\newcommand{\D}{\mathit{\Delta}}\sum_{t\in I\cup \D t\Bbb Z} c(t)(\D W_t^2-\D t).$$ The expectation of that is zero, the contributions are independent, so that the variation evaluates as $$\sum_{t\in I^{\D t}} c(t)^2(\D W_t^2-\D t)^2\sim [\int_Ic(t)^2dt]·\D t·E((Z^2-1)^2)$$ for a normal random reference variable $Z$. From that results the scale $\sqrt{\D t}$ of the global error of that method. Practically the error should converge to zero if $\D t$ goes to zero.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks. I'll give a more concrete example. Consider a set of two coupled stochastic variables x(t), y(t) and compare the following situations
*

Comment: It might be easier to add the illuminating example to the question text, especially if you can provide numerical experiments that contradict expectation in some way.

Comment: @LutzLehmann pressed enter too fast, and too late to edit. But yes, added the follow up in the text

Comment: What do you mean with "projected back to $0$"? Does this imply some proportional change to $x$? Do you imagine something like a stochastic process on a circle or sphere, where the SDE coefficients are orthogonal to the radius vector, but the E-M process without projection moves away from the sphere spiraling outward?

Comment: @LutzLehmann just changing y->0 and keeping x the same. This picture is what is known as a 'time-dependent variational principle' in physics. Basically, you approximate a dynamical system in a large space by another one in a smaller submanifold (in this example, the y=0 subspace), as close as possible to the true one. In a deterministic system,  at any given point in time the evolution within the manifold is tangential to what the full system would do. Here in the stochastic case, there should be order $dt$ deviations for individual timestep but still they share EM timesteps.

Comment: It may be that your example is too simple, in that you can set $y=0$ outright without changing anything. Or I am not thinking complicated enough. That's why I proposed the curved example. But even that might not be correct, as the Brownian motion on a circle has $dX=-0.5X\,dt+Y\,dW$ and $dY=-0.5Y\,dt-X\,dW$, where the Ito-correction is not tangential. Can you give a low-dimensional mockup example for the $y=0$ situation that exhibits the non-triviality of it?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm on your side kind of hoping that the answer to the question is yes. Just not really sure that it holds in general. Would need to think a bit more about it. Guess that the 'contributions are independent' part gives an important cue

Comment: @LutzLehmann how do we get the 'leading error term' in the multivariate case? Is it just the additional terms towards the Milstein method? I these become very complicated in the non-commutative case?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. If the Brownian motion is one-dimensional, the error is the same, $c$ is  $b'b$ or similar. In the case of multidimensional BM one gets mixed integrals that do not reduce to nice formulas, but still have about the same magnitudes.

Comment: @LutzLehmann aha, I guess that some kind of Lipschitz condition prevents the variance from blowing up... All these integrals average to zero and this is reached for t->0 by the central limit theorem?

Comment: Yes, as far as I remember, the integrals are of the type $\int_t^{t+dt}(W^j_s-W^j_t)dW^k_s$. For $j=k$ this can be integrated to $\frac12[(W_{t+dt}-W_t)^2-dt]$, but not for the others. But still, the expected value is zero and the variance is $E\Bigl[\int_t^{t+dt}(W^j_s-W^j_t)^2ds\Bigr]=\frac12dt^2$, so the general argument remains valid. And yes, the Lipschitz condition prevents that the coefficients of the estimate blow up.