# Moment of Ito diffusion computationally

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Say, we have an SDE

$$ \mathrm d X_t = f(X_t) \mathrm d t + \sigma(X_t) \mathrm d W_t $$

where $W_t$ is a Wiener process.

Assuming a strong solution exists globally (so the 1st and 2nd moments should be bounded), what is exactly

$$\mathbb E [X_t]$$

from the computation standpoint?

In discrete-time processes, if we have transition pdfs, it's quite clear, but in time-continuous case it seems difficult.

I tried to look up a pdf of $X_t$ knowing that of the driving noise, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Do you mean how do you evaluate it numerically? Draw a bunch of trajectories up to time $t$, record the value at time $t$, average the results.

Comment: Also not sure what you're looking for. Anyway, you do have transistion kernels also in the time-continuous setting.

Comment: @Tobsn Can you elaborate? I'm looking for a formal definition that gives a hint on how to compute it

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[X_{t}]=\int y p_{t}(x,dy)$ assuming $X_{0}=x$. Apart from rare special cases you won't be able to find explicit expressions for the Markov kernel $p$.

Comment: @Tobsn I am not talking about explicit methods. How is $p_t$ defined then? And why do we condition on $x$ there? What if $X_t$ "drifted" far from the initial state?

Comment: @RubiShnol If you aren't looking for an explicit method, what are you looking for?  Ian already gave you the numerical solution.

Comment: @user6247850 I am not looking for numerical solutions. Let me explain: if I have a discrete Markov process, I can "compute" (formally define if you will) moments using the transition pdf. In case of SDEs, how do I do this?

Comment: @RubiShnol One can show that (time homogenous) Ito diffusion processes are Markovian, and thus come along with a family of Markov transition kernels $p_{t}$. That's an abstract existence theorem if you like, no recipe for computation. Yet, under suitable assumptions on the coefficients one can show that these kernels (or actually their Lebsegue densities) satisfy the Fokker-Planck equation, as was pointed out already in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

1. One way is to numerically integrate the SDE similar to ODE. The expectation could be obtained by averaging many trajectories. See:
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method
2. Another way is to calculate the corresponded Fokker-Planck equation and solve this PDE numerically. Then, the expectation at given time can be obtained by taking the moment of the PDE solution at that time.

Comment: Let's say we fixed a small time interval $[0, \tau]$. How close are $\mathbb E[\hat X_t]$ and $\mathbb E[X_t]$, where $\hat X_t$ is the Euler-Maruyama approximate solution with the discretization step $\tau$?

Comment: I think it will depend on how $f$ and $\sigma$ behave on $[0, \tau]$ (e.g. Lipchitz condition etc.) There are some discussion here: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058518/does-an-euler-maruyama-scheme-correspond-to-a-unique-ito-sde

Answer (score 1):

$X$ can be thought of as just a collection of random variables $(X_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)},$ and their expected value can be defined the same way as any other random variable's.

More formally, let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space with a Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)} = (W_t(\omega))_{t \in [0,\infty)}$.  Since we assume $f$ and $\sigma$ satisfy sufficient regularity conditions to guarantee a strong solution exists, and strong existence of a solution implies pathwise uniqueness, we have a unique process $(X_t)_{t \in [0,\infty)} = (X_t(\omega))_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ satisfying $$dX_t = f(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t.$$  This process $X$ is the solution to the SDE, and the expected value of $X_t$ is defined by $$\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \int_{\Omega} X_t(\omega)d\mathbb{P}(\omega).$$

Comment: Ok, that's clear, but how is the respective pdf defined?

Comment: The pdf is defined the same way as for any other random variable, as the derivative of the CDF: $p_t(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \mathbb{P}(X_t \le z)$.  In general, this is not something that can be computed explicitly.  As @WHLin mentions in their answer, you can derive a PDE for it, but in general that will still not have an explicit solution.

Comment: It may fail to have a solution in general, as far as I understand.